# How can I complete "setup windows and configmgr" without network after cached deployment?

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012-r2

The situation is I have a ton of laptops with wifi already on the domain. I can create a task for an OSD, deploy it as pre-downloaded to ccmcache, and the thing mostly runs fine. It downloads everything, reboots to winPE, takes a long time for a couple steps (I assume timing out), but then gets as far as "setup windows and configmgr".

That's where it stops, because it cannot resolve the MP or DP. It shouldn't need to, as the package for config client should have been downloaded like everything else. But I guess it insists? Or maybe the package itself is what insists?

I really need this to work. How can I get past this step?  It's all that is holding me back right now. Once the task continues after reboot, the computer can import wifi, reconnect, install packages, join the domain, install ccm there if needed, etc.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would this get downvotes and no comments?  This is an immensely useful technique in an enterprise or education setting, especially as an alternative to custom wim's and janky wifi hacks. It's ridiculous.

Using source with the install options for configmgr stops it from insisting on getting the files online. You point it to where the package will store the client files. There's the answer.